# How to delete multiple cells in a sing row, and continue that for 50 rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to see if there is a way to delete cell A2, and then have google sheets automatically delete cells E2,G2,H2,I2. I would want this for each row for 50 rows. What is happening right now is if I delete A2, google sheets automatically pushes the next oldest data. however, it then pushes down cell E2,G2,H2,I2, because it didnt give me enough time to delete them. Help is appreciated.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10eK6tyHVIX6JyFChXYvtS6JmYyUnE-Ib0pClSnouBoU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want a row to be cleaned (except barcode cells) when column A has been deleted for your entire sheet? By `because it didnt give me enough time to delete them` what do you mean?

Comment: @JoseVasquez that is correct. If you access the google sheet that I attached, if you enter info into part number and line for row 2 & 3, and then delete the part number (A2) in row 2, row three will move up automatically. However, row 2 line, part number and timestamp will then move down into row 3. I want it to move up, but I want it to move up after all the data from that row is deleted. Is there a way to have the timestamp and line get deleted when I delete the part number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### By using a simple comparison inside your trigger you can delete the data

Here's my approach by using the code you provided inside the Sheet:

```
function onEdit(e){
  script1(e);
  script2(e);
}

function script1(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col === 1 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Kanban"){
    if (e.range.getValue() === '') {
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(`E${row}`).setValue('');
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(`H${row}`).setValue('');
    } else {
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).setValue(new Date());
    }
    
  }
}

function script2(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kanban");          
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:I");
  range.sort([{column: 8, ascending: true}]);   
}
```

Where `if (e.range.getValue() === '')` and `.setValue('');` will "delete" the data when it comes to first column and it's been deleted, otherwise it'll change the Timestamp cell.

### Reference

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much man